# Google Codelab Mistake

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build this application via Google Codelab.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/hello-beacons/#0

On page seven, I am stuck with a missing bracket

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/hello-beacons/#6

or to be more exact this piece of code:

```
SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
.setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
.setFilter(new MessageFilter.Builder()
    .includeNamespacedType("some_namespace", "some_type")
.build();
```

Android Studio throws an error here and expects ')'.

I tried

```
.setFilter(new MessageFilter.Builder())
```

but that didnt help. I am pretty lost, is it possible there is a bug in this code?

Comment: You are right there is an error in the code labs code, the closing parenthesis is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not only missing a bracket but a `build()` call as well. There are two builders yet only one `build()` call. It should be:

```
SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
    .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
    .setFilter(new MessageFilter.Builder()
        .includeNamespacedType("some_namespace", "some_type").build())
    .build();
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, now it works. I'll file a bug report.

Comment: @of_horse Was i right about the missing `build()` call as well?

Comment: Yeah, that's were I got stuck :)